Adding initials to custom bibtex type
I have created a custom bibtex type called personal communication with the following definition.
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{personalcommunication}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{include/bibliography.bib}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\mycite}{\cites}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}
  {}
  {\ifentrytype{personalcommunication}
      {\mkbibparens{\printnames{labelname} personal communication, \printfield{day} \printfield{month}, \printfield{year}}}
      {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{cite}}}%
  }
  {}
  {}

However when I autocite the following entry the initial of the persons first name isnt showing up as I want.
@personalcommunication{JS,
    author = {John Smith},
    date = {2024-03-26},
}

(Smith personal communication, 26 mars, 2024). How do I add this initial so it turns into (J. Smith personal communication, 26 mars, 2024)
